# What's the official term for the batting player in women's cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, terminology

In men's cricket, the term "batsman" or "batsmen" is used to refer to batting players - both by commentators as well as the respective cricket board score cards/commentaries.

But in women's cricket, what's the official/standard way to refer a batting player? "Batswoman"? "Batter"? "Batting player"?

Same for the fielder at third-man. Is that position called "third-woman"?
Same for "man-of-the-match". But I believe it has become "player of the match" in both men and women cricket. (At least since the last ICC Test Cup, or maybe before that.)

I tried getting the answer myself by watching a few matches, but couldn't get any conclusive answer.

Answer (score 6):

As of 22nd September 2021, "batter" is the offical term in both men's and women's cricket - see e.g. [Law 25 Batter's innings; Runners](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/batsman-s-innings;-runners).<sup>1</sup>

"Third man", "nightwatchman" and similar are not official terms so any usage here just vary depending on who is reporting on the match.

<sup>1. Ignore the URL; that uses the old terminology so as not to break old links.</sup>